# How to save Local time in Mysql database C#

Tags: c#, mysql, time

I am trying to make a system that logs reports of who comes into the system , the username and the Time the person logged into the system, now i get this 0000-00-00 00:00:00 as the time and i want it to always get something like this : 2017-10-12 05:30:35, My code looks like this :

```
  public void LodgeReport()
    {
        string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLDatabaseConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;

            //string time = string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss tt}", DateTime.Now);
            string time = localDate.ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy HH':'mm':'ss.fff");
            string sql2 = "insert into vms_db.login_reports (username,time) values (@username,@time)";
            using (MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(sql2, con))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userName.Text);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", time.ToString());
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

What am i Missing?

Comment: What's the type of your time column in the database? Do you really *have* to use a string representation?

Comment: @JonSkeet i used Datetime

Comment: @Markaz why are you converting the DateTime to a string then? MySQL will have to parse this back to a DateTime in order to store it, using *its* timezone settings. You may be getting different values simply because you force that double conversion. Just pass the `localDate` variable as the value of the `@time` parameter

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding using `AddWithValue` - use `cmd2.Parameters.Add("@time", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;` (although I'd strongly advise against storing local times in the database if you can, unless you really, really don't care about time zones... UTC is *usually* a better idea, particularly for timestamps). If you do that, what do you see in the database?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , yes that worked 100% thank you so so much!